# Adding background colour to parent table not working

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a three `row` table:

- **Row 1**: Image
- **Row 2**: Text
- **Row 3**: Line

I want the table to have a background of blue, and the line (`row 3`) to be white. So I've made a nested `table` in `row 3` in an attempt to add the `background-color` to that `table` and have the white line as a `td` within it - but it's just not working.

Here's what I want it to ideally look like:

[image]

Here's what mine looks like currently:

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <!--ROW 1 IMAGE -->
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-color:#00adf2;">
        <img alt="Contento" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/speech.png" style="display:block;border:0px;
                 font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#ffffff; padding-top: 5px;" width="310">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--ROW 1 TEXT -->
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="background-color:#00adf2; font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:24px;color:#fff;padding-top:10px; text-align: center;">
        Faceate volorunt uta quo moditas
        <br> et labo. Comnima iorehent hit est
        <br> am vit elit volores cimpossime
        <br> serchit, oditiis rehenis volor
        <br> sequisqui ut late cus. Faceate
        <br> volorunt uta quo moditas et labo.
        <br> Comnima ioreh.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!--ROW 3 LINE -->
      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding-top:32px;">
        <!-- NESTED TABLE -->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-color:#00adf2; width: 100%;" width="100%">
                <!-- TABLE FOR LINE -->
                <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#fff" height="3" style="height:4px;width:50px;font-size:0px;" width="130"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- TABLE FOR LINE END -->
              </td>
              <!-- LINE END -->
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- NESTED TABLE END -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you using `table`?

Comment: It's for a HTML email. I don't want to use div's since most email clients mess up the content on preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove borders, and add `background-color` to last `td` as well

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <!--ROW 1 IMAGE -->
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-color:#00adf2;">
        <img alt="Contento" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/speech.png" style="display:block;border:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#ffffff; padding-top: 5px;" width="310">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--ROW 1 TEXT -->
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="background-color:#00adf2; font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:24px;color:#fff;padding-top:10px; text-align: center;">
        Faceate volorunt uta quo moditas
        <br> et labo. Comnima iorehent hit est
        <br> am vit elit volores cimpossime
        <br> serchit, oditiis rehenis volor
        <br> sequisqui ut late cus. Faceate
        <br> volorunt uta quo moditas et labo.
        <br> Comnima ioreh.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!--ROW 3 LINE -->
      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding: 22px;background-color:#00adf2;vertical-align:top;">
        <!-- NESTED TABLE -->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width: 100%;" width="100%">
                <!-- TABLE FOR LINE -->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#fff" height="3" style="height:4px;width:50px;font-size:0px;" width="130"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- TABLE FOR LINE END -->
              </td>
              <!-- LINE END -->
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- NESTED TABLE END -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply your background color to main table

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color:#00adf2;">
```

check this out

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color:#00adf2;">
  <tbody>
    <!--ROW 1 IMAGE -->
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-color:#00adf2;">
        <img alt="Contento" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/speech.png" style="display:block;border:0px;
                 font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#ffffff; padding-top: 5px;" width="310">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--ROW 1 TEXT -->
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="background-color:#00adf2; font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:24px;color:#fff;padding-top:10px; text-align: center;">
        Faceate volorunt uta quo moditas
        <br> et labo. Comnima iorehent hit est
        <br> am vit elit volores cimpossime
        <br> serchit, oditiis rehenis volor
        <br> sequisqui ut late cus. Faceate
        <br> volorunt uta quo moditas et labo.
        <br> Comnima ioreh.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!--ROW 3 LINE -->
      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding-top:32px;">
        <!-- NESTED TABLE -->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-color:#00adf2; width: 100%;" width="100%">
                <!-- TABLE FOR LINE -->
                <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#fff" height="3" style="height:4px;width:50px;font-size:0px;" width="130"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- TABLE FOR LINE END -->
              </td>
              <!-- LINE END -->
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- NESTED TABLE END -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add background color to TD of 3rd row `<!--ROW 3 LINE -->`

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <!--ROW 1 IMAGE -->
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-color:#00adf2;">
        <img alt="Contento" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/speech.png" style="display:block;border:0px;
                 font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#ffffff; padding-top: 5px;" width="310">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--ROW 1 TEXT -->
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="background-color:#00adf2; font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:24px;color:#fff;padding-top:10px; text-align: center;">
        Faceate volorunt uta quo moditas
        <br> et labo. Comnima iorehent hit est
        <br> am vit elit volores cimpossime
        <br> serchit, oditiis rehenis volor
        <br> sequisqui ut late cus. Faceate
        <br> volorunt uta quo moditas et labo.
        <br> Comnima ioreh.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!--ROW 3 LINE -->
      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding-top:32px; background-color:#00adf2;">
        <!-- NESTED TABLE -->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-color:#00adf2; width: 100%;" width="100%">
                <!-- TABLE FOR LINE -->
                <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#fff" height="3" style="height:4px;width:50px;font-size:0px;" width="130"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- TABLE FOR LINE END -->
              </td>
              <!-- LINE END -->
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- NESTED TABLE END -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```